# Countdown timer with react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to implement countdown timer on my own just to know hooks more. I know there are libraries out there but don't want to use it. the problem with my code is, I cannot get updated state inside "timer" function which is updated in start timer function I'm trying to implement timer that will have triggers to start, stop, & resume & can be manually trigger. by other component that is using the countdown component

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Countdown = ({ countDownTimerOpt }) => {
  const [getObj, setObj] = useState({
    formatTimer: null,
    countDownTimer: 0,
    intervalObj: null,
  });

  const { formatTimer, countDownTimer, intervalObj } = getObj;

  if (countDownTimerOpt > 0 && intervalObj === null) {
    startTimer();
  }

  function startTimer() {
    const x = setInterval(() => {
      timer();
    }, 1000);

    setObj((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      countDownTimer: countDownTimerOpt,
      intervalObj: x,
    }));
  }

  function timer() {
    var days = Math.floor(countDownTimer / 24 / 60 / 60);
    var hoursLeft = Math.floor(countDownTimer - days * 86400);
    var hours = Math.floor(hoursLeft / 3600);
    var minutesLeft = Math.floor(hoursLeft - hours * 3600);
    var minutes = Math.floor(minutesLeft / 60);
    var remainingSeconds = countDownTimer % 60;

    const formatTimer1 =
      pad(days) +
      ':' +
      pad(hours) +
      ':' +
      pad(minutes) +
      ':' +
      pad(remainingSeconds);

    if (countDownTimer === 0) {
      clearInterval(intervalObj);
    } else {
      setObj((prev) => ({
        ...prev,
        formatTimer: formatTimer1,
        countDownTimer: prev['countDownTimer'] - 1,
      }));
    }
  }
  function pad(n) {
    return n < 10 ? '0' + n : n;
  }

  return <div>{formatTimer ? formatTimer : Math.random()}</div>;
};
export default Countdown;
```

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Timer from '../../components/countdown-timer/countdown.component';

const Training = () => {
  const [getValue, setValue] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const x = setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('setTimeout');
      setValue(10000);
    }, 5000);

    return () => clearInterval(x);
  }, []);

  return <Timer countDownTimerOpt={getValue} />;
```

don't want to use any set interval inside training page as the countdown component will also be used in exam page

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually with hooks I would combine your functionality into a custom hook and use it in different places.

```
const useTimer = (startTime) => {
    const [time, setTime] = useState(startTime)
    const [intervalID, setIntervalID] = useState(null)
    const hasTimerEnded = time <= 0
    const isTimerRunning = intervalID != null

    const update = () => {
        setTime(time => time - 1)
    }
    const startTimer = () => {
        if (!hasTimerEnded && !isTimerRunning) {
            setIntervalID(setInterval(update, 1000))
        }
    }
    const stopTimer = () => {
        clearInterval(intervalID)
        setIntervalID(null)
    }
    // clear interval when the timer ends
    useEffect(() => {
        if (hasTimerEnded) {
            clearInterval(intervalID)
            setIntervalID(null)
        }
    }, [hasTimerEnded])
    // clear interval when component unmounts
    useEffect(() => () => {
        clearInterval(intervalID)
    }, [])
    return {
        time,
        startTimer,
        stopTimer,
    }
}
```

You can of course add a reset function or do other changes but use could look like this:

```
const Training = () => {
    const { time, startTimer, stopTimer } = useTimer(20)
    return <>
        <div>{time}</div>
        <button onClick={startTimer}>start</button>
        <button onClick={stopTimer}>stop</button>
    </>
}
```

Comment: can you explain why i was was getting countDownTimer = 0 inside timer() function even though the state was changing

Comment: I think it's because of a concept called [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures). `setInterval` gets called on the first render and `timer` was created inside the component. Therefore `timer` has access to `countDownTimer` in the first place. On the next render the state will have changed and a new `timer` function with access to the changed state will be created, but the interval will still call the old `timer` function.

Comment: Ok thanks, I have updated your code as per my requirements inside your custom hooks i have return setTime then inside training component removed startTimer onclick added useEffect in training component made network call the used setTime than call startTimer() here the settime works fine but not the startTimer()

Answer (score 3):

You can create a `useCountDown` Hook as follow (In Typescript) :

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/JT501/856a5950964502cf54e7be06adb9b2f0)

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

export const useCountDown: (
  total: number,
  ms?: number,
) => [number, () => void, () => void, () => void] = (
  total: number,
  ms: number = 1000,
) => {
  const [counter, setCountDown] = useState(total);
  const [startCountDown, setStartCountDown] = useState(false);
  // Store the created interval
  const intervalId = useRef<number>();
  const start: () => void = () => setStartCountDown(true);
  const pause: () => void = () => setStartCountDown(false);
  const reset: () => void = () => {
    clearInterval(intervalId.current);
    setStartCountDown(false);
    setCountDown(total);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    intervalId.current = setInterval(() => {
      startCountDown && counter > 0 && setCountDown(counter => counter - 1);
    }, ms);
    // Clear interval when count to zero
    if (counter === 0) clearInterval(intervalId.current);
    // Clear interval when unmount
    return () => clearInterval(intervalId.current);
  }, [startCountDown, counter, ms]);

  return [counter, start, pause, reset];
};
```

Usage Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/usecountdown-hook-56lqv